# Where to send JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, google-maps

I have set up a rails app which simply displays a google maps page.
In my application.html.erb file I have the following variable which sets the coordinates on the map:

```
var markers = [

    ['Auckland Central', -36.848460, 174.763332],
    ['Location', -36.826768, 174.795208]

];
```

I want to send the JSON below to the app and update the 'Location' coordinates with the JSON.

```
"json": {                                                                                                                                                       
     "latitude": -36.827308333,                                                                                                                                    
     "longitude": 174.810091667                                                                                                                                    
},
```

Where would I send the data and how would I get it into the markers variable?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use `gon` gem.

```
# In controller
gon.coordinates = {
  :latitude => -36.827308333,
  :longitude => 174.810091667
}

// In JavaScript
alert(JSON.stringify(gon.coordinates));
```

I don't understand what you mean when saying that you need to send data to the app. If you need to input coordinates in browser, then you can implement form using form_for helper. You can create regular form. If you want you can implement AJAX form using either rails remote forms (http://www.codebeerstartups.com/2012/12/ajaxify-your-site-with-remote-true), or using jQuery.ajaxForm plugin (http://malsup.com/jquery/form/).

Comment: I have a device that is sending the GPS coordinates as JSON to a url. Problem is, I dont know what URL to send them to...

Comment: @Nerdtastic You should create controller and action. Run this command in console: `rails generate controller coordinates create`. It will generate page with `coordinates/create` URL.

Write this code in `create` action to see all parameters:
`raise params.to_yaml # Show all GET and POST parameters`

You can also open routes.rb and change `get "coordinates/new"` to `post "coordinates/new"`. I think POST request will be more appropriate for API.

Comment: @Nerdtastic I suggest you to read some ruby on rails tutorial. You need to understand controllers, actions, view, models, etc
Here are 2 good tutorials:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html
https://www.railstutorial.org/book

Comment: @Nerdtastic If you want, you can save coordinates in database. For example, in `coordinates` table.
So you can put locations into database in `coordinates/create` and render google map in `coordinates/index`.